# In android, tab layout getting improper view in landscape mode

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

[image: This is what my app getting in landscape mode]

[image: and this is what I want in landscape mode]

I made an application with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout and when I am switching the app into landscape mode, the tab will not fit into the window. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: thanks @abhishek patel, I forgot to put   app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"